# I want to find the XPATH of an element by knowing it's value

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

Here's my code:

```
def start_server(server_ip = None):
    
    content = driver.page_source
    root = html.fromstring(content)
    tree = root.getroottree()
    result = root.xpath('//*[. = "MythicalNoobsSMP"]')
    print(root,tree,result,end="\n")
    
start_server('MythicalNoobsSMP')
```

What I basically want to find is from aternos.org, I want to open the server profile requested by the function's param. Like here are the list of my servers:-[image]
I want to open the MythicalNoobsSMP server basically so how do I get it's XPATH? *(Note, I don't want to get it from the dev tools → inspect)*

Comment: What is the problem with your current XPath : '//*[. = "MythicalNoobsSMP"]' ?
Could you also share the relevant html?

Comment: lxml has a method `getpath()`: https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#generating-xpath-expressions so hopefully in the context of HTML it works as well with e.g. `tree.getpath(result[0])`.

Comment: There is no such thing as "the XPath" for a node. There are an infinite number of possible XPath expressions that will give you that node. Which one you choose depends on how much you know about the structure of the page you are looking at (which means anticipating what parts of the page are stable, and what parts are subject to change.)

Answer (score 1):

So you already have this right?

```
result = root.xpath('//*[. = "MythicalNoobsSMP"]')
```

Once you need to check what kind of element it is. If its a `span` or an `a`.

Then basically you can create a generic xpath by saying

```
//elementname[text()='Your specific text']
```

For instance, to find a `span` with the value "MythicalNoobsSMP":

```
//span[text()='MythicalNoobsSMP']
```

This will work for all future references

Comment: Well I tried it all. But if you go into the aternos sources. Then the XPATH for this is:
```/html/body/div[1]/main/section/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]```